# Zoom image with next and previouse button in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

Right now i am using materialize design and i want to implement click to zoom functionality. I have seen one link and i want to implement like [this.http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-Touch-enabled-jQuery-Image-Lightbox-Plugin/](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-Touch-enabled-jQuery-Image-Lightbox-Plugin/)

MY CODE:

```
<a href="<catalog:ProductImageUrl pictureId="${pic.pictureId}" productName="${product.name}" useCase="zoom"/>">
  <img data-bigimgurl="<catalog:ProductImageUrl pictureId="${pic.pictureId}" productName="${product.name}" useCase="descriptionPageBig"/>" 
                                         width="60" class="prod-zoom-img" src="<catalog:ProductImageUrl pictureId="${pic.pictureId}" productName="${product.name}" useCase="modal-giftbox"/>" alt="view ${product.name}" title="${product.name}">
</a>
```

I am working in this page https://www.winni.in/bangalore/black-forest-cake/p/157?rfcid=4

SCREEN SHOT:
[image]

Materialize design provide zoom functionality but its have not previous and next button for change image.
I am searching some easy for this. Give me some idea for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use lightbox - http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/.

You basically need to

1. Include the lightbox js and css files in your page.
2. Add a `data-lightbox` attribute to the links you want to open.

For instance an attribute would be `data-lightbox="image_collection_name"`
where `image_collection_name` is an arbitrary name that shows the pictures are a part of the same collection (and you can browse them with the arrows)